# May I ask for product reviews or is it considered a shopping question?

Tags: discussion, questions, recommendations

I would like to ask the following question

> In my country, you can't find Lee Oskar or Hohner or Suzuki
>   harmonicas, i bought mine from the states on amazon. Everyone sells
>   Yamaha here.
>
> I'm looking to buy a Lee Oskar key of D, but I have two choice: buying
>   it online - or buying a yamaha instead.
>
> How good are Yamaha harmonicas? Do you know anything about them? I searched for days, on google and youtube and i can't find any review. Yamaha is known for making keyboards, but what about harmonicas? how good are they when compared to Hohner or Lee Oscar or Suzuki?

Is it considered a shopping question? Will it be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one would not be on topic here, as it is product recommendation. The questions of this type which do work here are ones which ask what features are useful or essential when purchasing an instrument, for example.

Also, in almost all cases, preferences are not based on objective qualities.

I may prefer electric guitars made of pine, while someone else may demand rosewood fretboard, and someone else may suggest semiacoustics are the only way to go.

In your case I might actually suggest that if you want a Lee Oskar you buy it online and get it shipped to you.

Comment: Yamaha harmonicas aren't being sold in USA at all, and there's nothing on the yamaha.com website about harmonicas, so i wanted to know how they compare to lee oskar or hohner or suzuki, anyway yes i kinda knew it was going to be closed here and so I asked on some other forums/websites right after i posted this question here

Comment: No worries - there are loads of sites that do product recommendations very well, it just doesn't fit the model here, unfortunately. Best of luck getting a good one.